# Faker Api not returning country specific address

Tags: java, faker

I'm trying to Use com.github.javafaker API to write some robust test scripts. API has a Locale specific constructor, But it's not returning the locale country specific address.

I wrote a sample Junit to test only the fakerApi before relying on it to test my app.

```
public class FakerUtils {

    public static Faker getFakerByISO3CountryCode(String ISO3CountryCode) {
        return SingletonWrapperFaker.countryCodeFakerMap.get(ISO3CountryCode);
    }

    private static class SingletonWrapperFaker {
        static Map<String, Faker> countryCodeFakerMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales())
           .forEach(locale -> {
                try {
                     countryCodeFakerMap.put(locale.getISO3Country(), new Faker(locale));
                }catch(Exception e){
                //every locale is not implemented.
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public static Faker getRandomFaker() {
        return null; //TODO: implement it
            }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
public class FakerUtilsTest {
@Test
    public void testGFakerByISO3CountryCode() {
        Address address =  FakerUtils.getFakerByISO3CountryCode("USA").address();       
        assertEquals("US",address.countryCode());
    }
}
```

every time it's returning a different country. 
I thought Maybe API has a restriction to create only one type of object. 
So I tried to not to populate map with Fakers but just kept locale in map for quick lookup and created a new locale based faker object upon every getFaker...() call. but still not avail

**UPDATE AFTER DEBUGGING**

I realize the api is not meant to be used the way I was using. 
Locale are just to translate in the give language.
A same object created with locale for example Locale.FRANCE can return different country/address or anything in the world irrespective of the constructor argument. 
It's a really random API,It serves a different purpose.

I called .countryCode() on same object in debug session. 
I got address object by providing a locale for USA in Faker constructor but every time a new country code is returned.

```
address.countryCode()
     (java.lang.String) GN
     (java.lang.String) LC
     (java.lang.String) SH
     (java.lang.String) NF
     (java.lang.String) BZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Faker API uses resources to generate data.
I looked through resource for USA locale: https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/master/src/main/resources/en-US.yml and I didn't find `address.country_code` path which are use [here](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/javafaker/Address.java#L103).

Your problem are explained [here](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/issues/268)

> There is a problem there which is caused by lack of data for that locale. So all locales will default to the english locale if there is no data specific to that locale. So country will look for French data but when that doesn't exist, it'll use the English one.

If you have a access to Locale, you should to use country code from Locale.